PHP Big Query Write Client Batch Add Rows
I'm not entirely sure what I need to ask for since I'm not certain I'm understanding Google's documentation.  What I want to be able to do is take data we've collected over the last 30 days and send it in batches to BigQuery.
I'm using two different API clients, Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Storage\V1\Client\BigQueryWriteClient and Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient.
Using BigQueryClient, I was able to figure out crud operations for datasets and tables.  For batch inserts this is what I've figured out so far.
I can retrieve table information using the standard BigQueryClient and then use the WriteClient and table identity information to create a write stream.  I then use the write stream to create an AppendRowsRequest, and pass that to the BidiStream returned from WriteClient->appendRows().  That's as far as I could get with the docs.  The examples provided never show adding row data, just getting streams and writing.
References:
https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-bigquery-storage/latest/V1.Client.BigQueryWriteClient
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api
https://googleapis.github.io/gax-php/v1.26.1/Google/ApiCore.html
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/main/BigQueryStorage/samples/V1/BigQueryWriteClient
What I have so far:
$client = new BigQueryClient();
$writeClient = new BigQueryWriteClient();

$table = $client->dataset($datasetId)->table($tableId);
$tableIdentity = $table->identity();
$parent = $writeClient::tableName(
    project: $tableIdentity['projectId'],
    dataset: $tableIdentity['datasetId'],
    table: $tableIdentity['tableId']
);
$writeStreamOptions = ['type' => Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Storage\V1\WriteStream\Type::PENDING];
$streamCreationRequest = CreateWriteStreamRequest::build(
    $parent, 
    new WriteStream($writeStreamOptions)
);

$writeSteam = $writeClient->createWriteStream($streamCreationRequest);
$appendRowRequest = AppendRowsRequest::build($writeSteam->getName());

$bidiStream = $this->writeClient->appendRows();
$bidiStream->write($appendRowRequest);

Where do add actual table data in this flow?  I'm trying to implement the Pending Type API Flow.

Batch loading data from cloud storage to Bigquery  you can follow this PHP
Loading data from local files .

@souravDutta this is about BigQuery Write Storage API and it's different from the BigQuery API

I'm also struggling with this and can't figure out how to pass the actual data. Getting the following error: { "message": "Request couldn't be served.", "code": 5, "status": "NOT_FOUND", "details": [] }
